# Creating a trigger containing St_intesects in Postgres

Tags: postgis, st-intersects, postgresql-9.6

I am new to SQL. I need a help creating a simple trigger function that can contain records from a intersection.
I have points layer(vnp14imgtdl_nrt_global_24h) and a polygon boundary(states).
The trigger needs to fetch all new records that are inserted into jharkhandfire layer that overlap the polygon boundary into the new table.
Is it possible?

The trigger function is shown below:

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.firefunc()
    RETURNS trigger
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    VOLATILE
    COST 100
AS $BODY$   BEGIN
      select(new.gid, new.latitude, new.longitude, new.bright_ti4, new.scan, new.track, new.acq_date, new.acq_time, new.satellite, new.confidence, new.version, new.bright_ti5, new.frp, new.daynight, new.geom);
      into jharkhandfire
      from public.vnp14imgtdl_nrt_global_24h
      where st_intersects(new.geom, states.geom);
      RETURN NEW;
   END;
$BODY$;
```

But this function gives error: error near into

Comment: What triggers the function?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. While fundamentally simple, triggers are generally considered to be an advanced topic, unsuitable for your first attempt at coding. There is a further complication, in that triggers are SQL entities more than they're GIS, so the proper place to ask about triggers is probably over in [dba.se]. When you have triggers down, if you still have PostGIS issues, then that would be the time to post here, with a representative sample of the code you have written, and a description of what isn't working.

Comment: One problem seems to be that you have a semi-colon at the end of your select line before the into clause.

Comment: I tried removing the semicolon but with no solution

Comment: enclosing brackets will try to combine column values into a *record* type; unless your table has a record column, try removing them